# Merge SQL rows based on multiple equal rows

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have three tables, users, principles, and users_principles. In the user_principle table, the users and principles are linked by their ids. I have the following table results.

```
ID   NAME     DESCRIPTION   PRINCIPLES
1    PHILIP   DEVELOPER     100
1    PHILIP   DEVELOPER     101
1    PHILIP   DEVELOPER     105
3    STEFAN   ACCOUNTANT    101
3    STEFAN   ACCOUNTANT    105
5    MIKE     CTO           120
5    MIKE     CTO           122
```

And I want the rows to be merged together since the principles is the only value that's different (all the other columns have the same values). So to get the results shown as below.

```
ID   NAME     DESCRIPTION   PRINCIPLES
1    PHILIP   DEVELOPER     100, 101, 105
3    STEFAN   ACCOUNTANT    101, 105
5    MIKE     CTO           120, 122
```

```
select users.id, users.name, users.description, users_principles.principleId from
    users
    join users_principles on users_principles.userId = users.id
where users.id > 0;
```

I tried with groupConcat, but that only works for one single ID, and when I have all of the users (users.id > 0), nothing makes sense in the table. Also 'STUFF()' is not an option since it doesn't exist in mariadb. Additionally I have to make it work in jooq, but first trying to get it working in sql.

Anyone with any suggestions please?

Comment: I don't understand how `group_concat()` didn't work. This is specifically what it's designed for. Perhaps you neglected to add a `GROUP BY` clause? `SELECT users.id, users.name, users.description, GROUP_CONCAT(users_principles.principleId) as PRINCIPLES FROM users INNER JOIN users_principles ON users_principles.userId = users.id
WHERE users.id > 0 GROUP BY users.id, users.name, users.description`

Comment: What happen with `GROUP_CONCAT(Id, Name, Description ORDER BY Principles) AS Priciples`?

Comment: Made it with with adding a 'group by users.id'! I guess it needs to know by which parameters which groups of the same rows it needs to take - I guess this would work if I put any of the other columns that are the same too.